# select all and avg from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

Please could you help to get the query for described situation below:

```
1 TABLE: shops:    id | name | is_locked   |
2 TABLE: products: id | name | price       | shop_id 
3 TABLE: rates:    id | rate | is_accepted | shop_id
```

I've got 3 tables with shops, shop's products and rates. And now I would like to sort all products, which belong to the not locked shop and order by average of the accepted shop rates. How should this query look like?

Comment: Kindly share table sample data, expected result and the query you tried so far(incomplete, bad, worst whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select p.name, p.price, AVG(r.rate) 
from shops s, products p, rates r 
Where s.is_locked <> 1 and
      s.id = p.shop_id and
      s.id = r.shop_id and
      p.shop_id = r.shop_id
group by p.id 
order by AVG(r.rate)
```

Comment: unfortunately AVG(r.rate) is the same for all products, it don't recognise shop_id...

Comment: @jdoe Edited my answer. Please check now.

Comment: ok, I think that group by is missing. Thank you for guiding me on the right solution :)

Comment: @jdoe added. Thanks.